# yarn install warning on package has empty message

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I'm running `yarn install`. Part of the output is as follows:

```
yarn install v1.10.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @beaker/webdb > level-browserify > level-js > xtend > object-keys@0.4.0:
```

The question: **What does this warning mean?**

---

**More info**

The whole output:

```
yarn install v1.10.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @beaker/webdb > level-browserify > level-js > xtend > object-keys@0.4.0: 
warning karma > log4js > circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "angular4-material-table > @angular/forms@6.1.10" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/platform-browser@6.1.10".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 202.88s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that `object-keys@0.4.0` has been marked as deprecated, but there is no message.

You can see via

```
npm view object-keys@0.4.0 --json
```

that there is a `deprecated` field with an empty string. I'm not sure how npm clients are supposed to treat this but `yarn` simply checks if [`deprecated` is a string](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/6db39cf0ff684ce4e7de29669046afb8103fce3d/src/resolvers/registries/npm-resolver.js#L200) and displays a warning with the provided deprecation message.

Unfortunately, the warning doesn't say anything about it being about a deprecation and coupled with an empty message, you end up with a mystery warning.

Answer (score 0):

The warning means your project uses `karma`, which depends on `log4js`, which in turn depends on `CircularJSON`, and that the latter [has been deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-json) in favour of [`flatted`](https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted), a newer package.

Comment: Thank you but I'm asking about the one above it: `warning @beaker/webdb > level-browserify > level-js > xtend > object-keys@0.4.0: ` (note the no-message).